# What of HTML5 and the Browser DOM is supported in Chromecast

Tags: chromecast

The documnentation says that Chromecast is using a "Scaled down" version of the Chrome Browser. 
Is there somewhere a list of supported HTML5 tags and supported JavaScript DOM actions?

I like to build a UX in HTML5 for Chromecast that I can remote control from a mobile phone or desktop browser. Video is only secondary in this solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of a comprehensive list like that. You need to keep in mind that Chromecast devices are geared toward consumption of media, so there is a pretty good support for the MediaElements there. In fact it has some additional media extensions such as EME and MSE. In terms of the DOM actions, I suggest to minimize (or better stay away, if possible) of any fancy transitions; the support for most things is there but it is not optimized and the resources required for those to be smooth (i.e. hardware/memory) is scarce on that device.

If you need to find more about the coverage and performance, I suggest you write a simple app that puts any of the many javascript test pages and see the result on the actual device.

Comment: thanks, the page I created is creating dynamic HTML5 elements using the DOM. No fancy elements just standard divs. But the javascript creating the page is quite elaborate including the use of JQuery and ajax calls to get the metadata.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21587351/2687479) has that list you're looking for. I also [self answered the question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20928634/2687479) with some of the weird quirks I've run into that might affect the type of tech you decide on using.